# How to identify if the type c port on my laptop has Display / thunderbolt support?

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-monitor

I am typing to connect an external display using the type c 3.1 gen 2 on my laptop external adapters, but the HDMI connection via the adapter is not able to connect the external display.

I am trying to figure out if type C on my laptop is capable of supporting this external display.

Comment: I think the best way is checking with the manufacturer. If such feature isn't mentioned then it hasn't it.

Comment: Like he said. The maker would know.